# calling broadcast receiver class multiple times with different intent showing "null pointer error"

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

my app has a BroadcastReciving and mainactivity class.
from mainactivity  I am calling broadcast receiving class 3 times with different intent from different places.

what i want is to execute different codes in broadcast receiving class when found different intent.

```
eg: 
   when intent contains string it execute a() function
   when intent is int it executes b() function
```

**but when i am fetching data in on receive it crashes my app showing "null pointer Exception" how to solve this**

Comment: Where is your code and logcat error ?

Comment: Can you show your code here ?
Make sure you registered for all three intents also, check in onReiceive() weather the intent is not null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a different action string for each different operation. Set the action for each `Intent` appropriately and check the action in onReceive of the `BroadcastReceiver`.

```
/* when sending a broadcast */
Intent intent = new Intent("action_a");
context.sendBroadcast(intent);

/* in the BroadcastReceiver */
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    final String action = intent.getAction();
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(action)) {
        // intent didn't have an action
        return;
    }

    if ("action_a".equals(action)) {
        // do function A
    } else if ("action_b".equals(action)) {
        // do function B
    } // and so on
}
```

In your AndroidManifest, add the following as a child element of the `<receiver>` tag:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action name="action_a" />
    <action name="action_b" />
    <!-- and so on -->
</intent-filter>
```